# Tabview default animation doesn't occur for the first time if switching tabs programatically

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I noticed after I have embedded TabView into NavigationStack, a default animation while switching between tabs (when pressing Next button) has disappeared. So transition to a next tab is instant. Here is part of code I am using:

```
  var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack {
            TabView(selection: $viewModel.selection) {
                ForEach(viewModel.onboardingData, id: \.self) { data in
                    OnboardingView(data: data)
                        .tag(data.identifier)
                }
            }
            .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .always))
            .indexViewStyle(.page(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
            HStack {
                skipButton
                Spacer()
                nextButton
            }
        }
    }
```

and the button:

```
 private var nextButton: some View {
        Button(action: {
            withAnimation {
                viewModel.next()
            }

    }) {
        if viewModel.selection == .fourth {
            NavigationLink(destination: HomeView()) {
                button(text: "Let's start")
            }
        } else {
            button(text: "Next")
        }
    }
}
```

If I remove NavigationStack, things will work, but right now, only for the first item (when going from first to the second tab) animation is not happening. I guess its probably something obvious, but I don't understand it.

EDIT: @Benzy Neez

```
 private func button(text: String) -> some View {
            return Text(text)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .padding(.vertical, 22)
                .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                .background(Color.teal)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .padding()
        }
```

this is how a button making function looked like.

Comment: Probably a bug, TabView changes in its core when embedded in a NavigationStack + page.

Comment: I thought it might work nicely with `.page` option. I mean it almost works :(. So I guess the solution is to make everything custom? @loremipsum

Comment: Maybe submit a bug report it might get fixed. TabView is different, this whole changing thing based on parent/style is unique as far as I know. Custom might be the way to go, scroll view was vastly improved in iOS 17.

Comment: Have you tried by replacing `ForEach(viewModel.onboardingData, id: \.self)` with -> `ForEach(viewModel.onboardingData, id: \.identifier)`

Comment: @SPatel I just did. Got the same result :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The label for your `nextButton` is either a `NavigationLink` (which is itself a button) or a `button`. Is `button` a styled label, or is it a nested `Button`?

In any case, I would suggest changing `nextButton` and removing the `NavigationLink`. This can be done by moving the if-then switch to the `HStack` with the buttons. In other words, the `HStack` should either show `nextButton`, or it should show a `NavigationLink`. Also, if `button` contains a nested `Button` then I would change that too, it should just be a styled label.

I tried to reproduce the problem by improvising the gaps and the animation works for me. Here's the complete code, maybe you can see something being done differently:

```swift
enum OnboardingData: CaseIterable {
    case first
    case second
    case third
    case fourth

    var next: OnboardingData {
        let result: OnboardingData
        switch self {
        case .first: result = .second
        case .second: result = .third
        case .third: result = .fourth
        case .fourth: result = .first
        }
        return result
    }

    var identifier: OnboardingData {
        self
    }
}

class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let onboardingData = OnboardingData.allCases

    @Published var selection = OnboardingData.first

    func next() {
        selection = selection.next
    }
}

struct HomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("HomeView")
    }
}

struct OnboardingView: View {
    let data: OnboardingData
    var body: some View {
        Text("OnboardingView for \(String(describing: data))")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @StateObject private var viewModel = MyViewModel()

    private func button(text: String) -> some View {
        Text(LocalizedStringKey(text))
            .padding()
            .foregroundStyle(.white)
            .background(.gray)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6))
            .padding(.horizontal)
    }

    private var nextButton: some View {
        Button {
            withAnimation {
                viewModel.next()
            }
        } label: {
            button(text: "Next")
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                TabView(selection: $viewModel.selection) {
                    ForEach(viewModel.onboardingData, id: \.self) { data in
                        OnboardingView(data: data)
                            .tag(data.identifier)
                    }
                }
                .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .always))
                .indexViewStyle(.page(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
                HStack {
                    button(text: "Skip") // skipButton
                    Spacer()
                    if viewModel.selection == .fourth {
                        NavigationLink(destination: HomeView()) {
                            button(text: "Let's start")
                        }
                    } else {
                        nextButton
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It actually works. I have no idea though why my code doesn't work. If I use ur code, and replace it in another project with all my classes, then it works :) The only difference I see, is that with ur example, I kept all the code in one file. In my project they are all separated. I don't know, I will look again later. But thanks anyway for confirming it works.

Comment: @Whirlwind Pleased to hear you got it working, thanks for accepting the answer. The definition of `button` looks fine, if that's plugged in to the code in this answer then it still works fine. So maybe it has something to do with identity, as SPatel was alluding to?